# Linux or Hypervisor solutions to run windows in vm, with multi monitor and passthrough supporting Adobe Creative Cloud

Tags: windows, linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, operating-system

I'm searching a setup that could replace my previous windows only based config.

I would like a secure linux based environment that would support virtual machines with multi monitor and gpu passthrough.

The goal is use all the adobe creative cloud inside a main windows vm with the dedicated gpu, and in multi monitor but still have the capability to run other linux VMs.

What could I use?

- ubuntu 22 lts, kvm and virt-manager ?
- ubuntu 22 and vmware workstation?
- proxmox?
- xen ?

I could go for a bare metal aka tier1 virtualization one but I need to use the machine with 3 monitors and everything, I can't use it headless, it's a high end desktop machine not a server closed in a dedicated room. So I need to have a desktop like ubuntu could provide, I'm not sure for the other hypervisors, I used esxi in past and it was only available through the net.